# Got AccessDenied error when Synchronize Cognito

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, twitter, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to authenticate to AWSCognito using external provider - Twitter. That's my code to authenticate in Twitter:

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession * _Nullable session, NSError * _Nullable error) {
}];
```

That's what I give to credentials provider in logins:

```
- (AWSTask<NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *> *) twitterLogin {

    __block id<TWTRAuthSession> session = nil ;

    session = [((Twitter*)[Twitter sharedInstance]).sessionStore session];

    NSString* token = session.authToken;
    NSString* tokenSecret = session.authTokenSecret;

    NSString* login = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@;%@", token, tokenSecret];
    return [AWSTask taskWithResult: @{ AWSIdentityProviderTwitter : login }];
}
```

After auth, I get YES in a result of `[self.credentialsProvider isAuthentificated]`
But when I'm trying to synchronize on Cognito Dataset, I get an error: `Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoSyncErrorDomain Code=0 "null" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=null, NSLocalizedFailureReason=AccessDeniedException:}`
That's my IAM auth role:

```
{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "cognito-identity:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:cognito-identity:us-east-1:198578192657:identitypool/us-east-1:ccb1a09f-5bb7-42af-8ef2-3dede074be38"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "cognito-sync:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:cognito-sync:us-east-1:198578192657:identitypool/us-east-1:ccb1a09f-5bb7-42af-8ef2-3dede074be38/identity/*/dataset/*"
    }
```

What's wrong? Why I get an error?

Comment: I get same error. I haven't solved it yet. But it seems I need to refresh my credential with provider!

Comment: @Bernard write here the solution, please. If you'll solve this problem. It is still actual

Comment: @RustamKendzhaev if you look at the identityId in the AWS console do you see the login count is 0?  If it is 0, you have never gotten authenticated.  I know you found isAuthenticated is yes, but I am wondering if your logins response for twitter worked.

Comment: @RustamKendzhaev I solved it by adding unauthenticated user to my roles and made it as optional in the mobile hub. It creats unauth role automatically

Comment: Are you still seeing this issue? I see identities in this pool with twitter linked and datasets synchronized to it.

Comment: @JeffBailey I have this issue only after first attempt to authenticate on device/simulator. When i try the second time in the same session everything is ok.